# Is it possible to exclude a property from a transition style?

Tags: css, css-transitions

If I have an element:

```
.element {
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 3px solid #000;
  color: #aaa;
  transition: {???} .4s ease;
}
```

Can I exclude a property from the transition? For example, transition `background-color` and `color` but have the `border` change instantly?